# Babe PoA to NPoS migration

Tags: runtime, migration, babe, npos, poa

Here's my babe pallet configuration: I suppose that for PoA we want to keep the same
authority set

```rust
impl pallet_babe::Config for Runtime {
    type EpochDuration = EpochDuration;
    type ExpectedBlockTime = ExpectedBlockTime;
    type EpochChangeTrigger = pallet_babe::SameAuthoritiesForever;
    type DisabledValidators = Session;

    type KeyOwnerProofSystem = Historical;

    type KeyOwnerProof = <Self::KeyOwnerProofSystem as KeyOwnerProofSystem<(
        KeyTypeId,
        pallet_babe::AuthorityId,
    )>>::Proof;

    type KeyOwnerIdentification = <Self::KeyOwnerProofSystem as KeyOwnerProofSystem<(
        KeyTypeId,
        pallet_babe::AuthorityId,
    )>>::IdentificationTuple;

    type HandleEquivocation =
        pallet_babe::EquivocationHandler<Self::KeyOwnerIdentification, Offences, ReportLongevity>;

    type WeightInfo = ();
    type MaxAuthorities = MaxAuthorities;
}
```

What would possible happen during a migration from PoA to NPoS when I change
the line `ExternalTrigger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BABE does not really care about being PoA or NPoS.

Babe expects a set of authorities at the end of the day, and these authotities are received via implementing `SessionHandler`. In other words, through [`SessionHandler`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_session/trait.SessionHandler.html), the `pallet-babe` is informed of new authorities (coming from the `pallet-session`).

Whether those authorities are hardcoded or actually being elected via an election process determines if a chain is PoA or NPoS/DPoS.

If you want to mimic the path that Polkadot took, you can use the `pallet-staking`. With this pallet, you can have both PoA and NPoS (read [here](https://hackmd.io/KQLaAnOJTMS3xmet3Gle_g) for more information about configuring the staking pallet). If you set the [`Forcing`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/enum.Forcing.html) to be `None`, then no new eras are triggered in the staking pallet, and the initial authorities configured via genesis remain active forever, which is what a PoA chain essentially is. Once you allow new eras to be created, the staking pallet will enact new validators through whatever `ElectionProvider` it is given to it. You can still mimic a PoA chain by implementing a custom `ElectionProvider` that always elects the same set of validators.

---

In general, this is the structure of the Consensus/PoS pallets in substrate, in their default mode. Of course, as you see they are all connected with Rust traits so they have be swapped out when needed.

```
Consensus Pallets


    ┌──────────┐
    │          │
    │          │
    │          │
    │  BABE    │                  ┌─────────────────┐                 ┌──────────────────┐
    │          │                  │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │                  │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │                  │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │◄─┐               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    ├──────────┤  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    ├──────────┤  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │ SessionHandler│                 │  SessionManager │                  │
    │   AURA   ◄──┼───────────────┤    SESSION      ◄─────────────────┤     STAKING      │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    ├──────────┤  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    ├──────────┤  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │  │               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │◄─┘               │                 │                 │                  │
    │          │                  │                 │                 │                  │
    │  GRANDPA │                  └─────────────────┘                 └──────────────────┘
    │          │
    │          │
    │          │
    │          │
    │          │
    └──────────┘
```

Comment: Ok so basically:
1. iniitializing (at genesis) the `pallet_staking` with `force_era: ForceNone` blocks all election eras (and so the validator set in the session pallet) to be updated, effectively ensuring PoA.
2. During a migration to NPoS should be then sufficient to call `pallet_staking::force_new_era(root_origin)` should re-enable normal election cycle hence enabling normal DPoS/NPoS.  

Is all of this correct?

Comment: Yes, all correct.

Comment: @kianenigma hi, and how to update the BabeAuthorityWeight from a custom pallet?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good resource for converting POA to NPOS

https://github.com/kaichaosun/substrate-stencil/commits/master

Comment: You can remove aura from your code and use babe only .