How to make POS consensus using Frontier?
I have used https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier, compiled and started a node. Everything is working fine like transaction etc.
But I want a POS consensus where user can stake amount to become a validator. But I am clueless how this can be achieved.
I installed pallet-staking, but I don't know how to configure it.

This doesn't consider whether the chain is a frontier or not. However, it does matter if your chain is a parachain or a solochain.

I think its solochain, I just cloned the github repo and compiled and started as it is.

Frontier does not do anything with the process of block authoring. It creates a EVM-compatibility layer on top of Substrate. To convert the PoA to PoS consensus, you need to reconfigure the validator election of your runtime. There are a few other answers related to that topic already. Here is a very detailed explanation from the Parity expert: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4910/4965
